# Write atomically to a file using Write() with snprintf()

Tags: c, io, printf, buffer

I want to be able to write atomically to a file, I am trying to use the `write()` function since it seems to grant atomic writes in most linux/unix systems.

Since I have variable string lengths and multiple printf's,  I was told to use `snprintf()`  and pass it as an argument to the write function in order to be able to do this properly, upon reading the documentation of this function I did a test implementation as below:

```
int file = open("file.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
if(file < 0)
    perror("Error:");
char buf[200] = "";
int numbytes = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Example string %s" stringvariable);
write(file, buf, numbytes);
```

From my tests it seems to have worked but my question is if this is the most correct way to implement it since I am creating a rather large buffer (something I am 100% sure will fit all my printfs) to store it before passing to write.

Comment: `int numbytes = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Example string %s" stringvariable);` Be aware that `snprintf()` in that code can return a value greater than `sizeof(buf)` if the resulting complete output string would be long to fit in `buf`.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, `write()` is not atomic, not even when it writes all of the data supplied in a single call.
2. Use advisory record locking ([`fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)) in all readers and writers to achieve atomic file updates.

   fcntl()-based record locks work over NFS on both Linux and BSDs; flock()-based file locks may not, depending on system and kernel version. (If NFS locking is disabled like it is on some web hosting services, no locking will be reliable.) Just initialize the `struct flock` with `.l_whence = SEEK_SET, .l_start = 0, .l_len = 0` to refer to the entire file.
3. Use [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) to print to a dynamically allocated buffer:

   ```
    char *buffer = NULL;
    int   length;

    length = asprintf(&buffer, ...);
    if (length == -1) {
        /* Out of memory */
    }

    /* ... Have buffer and length ... */

    free(buffer);
   ```
4. After adding the locking, do wrap your `write()` in a loop:

   ```
    {
        const char       *p = (const char *)buffer;
        const char *const q = (const char *)buffer + length;
        ssize_t           n;

        while (p < q) {

            n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > 0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != -1) {
                /* Write error / kernel bug! */
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                /* Error! Details in errno */
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Although there are some local filesystems that guarantee `write()` does not return a short count unless you run out of storage space, not all do; especially not the networked ones. Using a loop like above lets your program work even on such filesystems. It's not too much code to add for reliable and robust operation, in my opinion.
5. In Linux, you can take [a write lease](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) on a file to exclude any other process opening that file for a while.

   Essentially, you cannot block a file open, but you can delay it for up to `/proc/sys/fs/lease-break-time` seconds, typically 45 seconds. The lease is granted only when no other process has the file open, and if any other process tries to open the file, the lease owner gets a signal. (If the lease owner does not release the lease, for example by closing the file, the kernel will automagically break the lease after the lease-break-time is up.)

   Unfortunately, these only work in Linux, and only on local files, so they are of limited use.
6. If readers do not keep the file open, but open, read, and close it every time they read it, you can write a full replacement file (must be on the same filesystem; I recommend using a lock-subdirectory for this), and hard-link it over the old file.

   All readers will see either the old file or the new file, but those that keep their file open, will never see any changes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is some kind of assignment where I have to use certain defined functions. In this case `write()` is assumed as always guaranteeing atomic writing. However you bring up some great points which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Regarding the `asprintf()`, to put it in simple terms let's say I'm working on a multithread program and each thread has a print in a loop, and each loop of each thread the buffer should be reset. if I declare the buffer through a pointer in each thread function like you did, and then use `asprintf()` to dynamically allocate to that buffer, does this guarantee that the buffer will be private for each thread? Meaning, that asprintf will alocate another bit of memory for that dynamic buffer? I'm having some trouble figuring that out.

Comment: @spacing: Yes, if you reset the pointer to NULL, `asprintf()` will allocate memory as if you called `malloc()`. Of course, allocating and freeing the memory for every single write is a lot of overhead. You could just use a per-thread persistent buffer pointer (`static __thread char *buffer_data = NULL; static __thread size_t buffer_size = 0;`) with `snprintf()`, reallocating a larger buffer whenever `snprintf()` returns `buffer_size-1` or larger -- but then you'd have to ensure each thread calls `free(buffer_data); buffer_data = NULL; buffer_size = 0;` before exiting (or being cancelled).

Comment: @spacing: Of course, just having local variables (`char *buffer_data = NULL; size_t buffer_size = 0;` initialized at the beginning of the thread function), and `realloc()`d as needed to make it large enough for `snprintf()`, is just as thread-local and safe. Of course, you still need a  `free(buffer_data)` before the thread function returns. Each thread running the function will allocate their own, separate, buffer.

Comment: *No, `write()` is not atomic, not even when it writes all of the data supplied in a single call.*  That's not true at all.  Per [the POSIX `write` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html): *A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process. This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a single reader. ...*  While not a guarantee for file I/O, most implementations don't have a different `write` implementation for pipes and files, so `write()` *de facto* is often atomic.

Comment: Note also this requirement from POSIX:  *Before successful return from write(), the file offset shall be incremented by the number of bytes actually written.*  Since the final file offset must be incremented by exactly the number of bytes written, atomicity is strongly implied.  If `write()` is *not* atomic, two interleaved writes would result in the wrong value of the file offset being visible in at least one of multiple threads calling `write()` on the same file descriptor.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That is so incorrect it is not even funny; you are severely misleading others. First, that passage is specific only to pipes and writes not more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes. Linux, as well as BSDs, most definitely do have different implementations for `write()` on files and pipes. In Linux, each filesystem tends to have their own, and pipes use `pipe_read()/pipe_write()` (see fs/read_write.c and fs/pipe.c). As to the file offset, it is specific to a file description, and involves only the *atomicity of a single file description*; it has nothing to do with the file contents.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Have you even *bothered* to read all the other questions and answers regarding the atomicity of `write()` operations posted to this site?  It appears not. `write()` is *de facto* atomic for variable amounts for almost all local file systems.  **YOU** are the one being misleading with your blanket, absolute, and absolutely- incorrect statement "`write()` is not atomic".  And **THEN** you have the temerity to say *I'm* misleading?!?!

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Just because they are popular, does not make them correct. I know what I am talking about, because I have verified it in Linux. In particular, when two processes issue overlapping writes with only partial data in page cache, the order in which the two processes are woken up determines if the two writes are interleaved. It is relatively rare -- especially since all careless testing leads the data to be cached in page cache, which all but eliminates the race window --, but it does occur.